# Set cartesian limits with moveit!

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, cartesian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I'm working with moveit in ros melodic and a Hyundai robot. When I generated the robot files I found a file labeled cartesian_limits.yaml as show below:

```
cartesian_limits:
  max_trans_vel: 18
  max_trans_acc: 20
  max_trans_dec: -30
  max_rot_vel: 15.7
```

**Is it possible to set cartesian limits with moveit?**

I want the robot to not move outside a defined box. Something like:

```
x_min_limit = -0.4
x_max_limit = 1.5
```

My Hyundai robot has this function and I want to implement it in the simulation to avoid wierd paths.

Is it possible to set this kind of function in cartesian_limits.yaml file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403542/set-cartesian-limits-with-moveit!/) by [mth_sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/103087/mth_sousa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nope, that `cartesian_limits.yaml` is for velocities and accelerations and it's only used for the Pilz motion planner. We probably should rename that file to make it more clear - thanks for the reminder.

On ROS2 Rolling or Humble you can use constrained planning to do what you want. Tutorial here:

https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/planning_with_approximated_constraint_manifolds/planning_with_approximated_constraint_manifolds_tutorial.html

To be honest I'm not sure if the "constraint manifolds" planning works in ROS1. Probably not Melodic since it's quite old now.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2022-07-08**:
I would also recommend trying the PRM* planner rather than the default RRTConnect. RRTConnect is fast to plan but it produces wild paths often.

**Comment by [mth_sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/103087/mth_sousa/) on 2022-07-08**:
Thanks for your answer! I will check PRM*